# How to later remove HealthKit from provisioning profile

Tags: swift, xcode, provisioning-profile, healthkit

I have a Watch-App and by creating a Distribution provisioning profile a few weeks ago, there was an option to enable HealthKit.

Now it turns out that I do not need HealthKit in the Watch App.
(and therefore did not activate it inside WatchKit Extension's - Target's - Capabilities as the following picture shows):

[image]

So far so good.

But now Xcode keeps giving me these 2 Warning messages (obviously since the original provisioning profile includes HealthKit but the settings in Xcode don't)...

```
Code Signing Warning: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: 
bundleID.watchkit.extension" for "MyApp WatchKit Extension" contains 
entitlements that aren't in the entitlements file: 
com.apple.developer.healthkit.access. To use these entitlements, add them to 
your entitlements file. Otherwise, remove unused entitlements from your 
provisioning profile.
```

I tried to follow the Apple manual and there is says that under [The developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios) (Certificates) one should be able to change the options a provisioning profile consists of.

So I did go there and pressed "Edit" on my provisioning profile of choice:

[image]

But here the bad surprise:

Unless the explanation in the manual - THERE ARE NO LONGER ANY SETTINGS-SWITCHES THERE ANYMORE WHERE TO CHANGE THE HealthKit ENABLE/DISABLE STATE !!

[image]

What is there to do in order to disable HealtKit ?

Also: Removing the old provisioning profile and trying to create a new one does not work - SINCE THIS PROVISIONING PROFILE CREATION MASK DOES NOT SHOW ANY ENABLE/DISABLE SWITCHES ANYMORE (NOT LIKE A COUPLE OF WEEKS AGO....!!!)

Answer (score 0):

Delete the provisioning profile in the Apple Developer Portal then create a new one

Comment: Nope - did not work, unfortunately ! Since what I asked about: The HealthKit-Option is no longer there at the mask where you add the new Provisioning profile (for App Store) - and therefore the same waring persists in my XCode project. Is there any other way ??

Answer (score 0):

On Apple Developer Account > Identifiers section, select your app bundle ID, then here you can untick HealthKit-related capabilities. Once this is done, you can regenerate the matching Provisioning Profile, and it should no longer have HealthKit.